# Do we have any examples of questions written entirely in latin?

Tags: discussion, questions

Do we have any example of it in this site, maybe with an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ergative Man! I would direct you to the Chat portion of our site: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm

Here is an example of a recent exchange where I asked who wrote a particular quotation:

Sebastian: Quidam rogantes valde celeriter responsa distinguunt hamo viride.

Nickimite: Bene dictum! Est poeticum. Auctorne notus hoc scripsit?

Sebastian: Forsitan scripserit Ovidius? Scio non posse fuisse M. Valerium Martialem, verbo "mentula" conspicue absente.

I would love to chat with you too, I'm sure!

Comment: Sebastian (or the mysterious poet) should of course have written: *hamo viridi* (with a green check mark).

Answer (score 3):

Prima quaestio mea quidem posita est in lingua Latina:

[Accusativus 'Graecus' pertinetne ullo modo ad accusativum temporis?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/108/accusativus-graecus-pertinetne-ullo-modo-ad-accusativum-temporis)

Responsum vero in Anglica.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many!

Ben Kovitz has written several: [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/quomodo-cochlear-a-cochlea-est-ortum), [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/95/ignis-solis-propinqui), [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/98/dies-unus-non-primus?rq=1), [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/295/quando-a-fortiori-ortum-est). Cerberus mentioned one of his in the other post. I wrote one too ([here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/oro-dominum-vel-oro-ad-dominum)). I'm sure there are many more, but I don't know a systematic way to search for them.

Comment: If you can think of good keywords that must appear in a Latin question, you can search pretty easily. [Here's what you get for *cur*.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+cur) There's quite a bit of work in coming up with good words and filtering false positives.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta What about creating a tag for them? Way easier and probably interesting in itself.

Comment: The network discourages metatags as this would be, but I think we could have one if there's sufficient demand. If you make that into a meta question, we'll see what people think.